# Is it possible to save a HTML canvas as a image with ONLY Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am working on a QR Code project and some image is generated via Canvas. So they are not actually images. And users can't download/save it by hitting a "save as" context menu item.

How do I let the users able to download it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? How are you generating the image on the canvas?

Comment: window.open(canvas.toDataURL())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your "Save as" button look something like this (uninitialized, see below):

```
<a href="#" id="saveas" download="">Save as</a>
```

Then when you have created the QR code on canvas do the following to initialize it:

```
/// QR created here..

var link = document.getElementById('saveas');

link.download = 'filename.png';  /// set a filename or a default
link.href = canvas.toDataURL();  /// create a data-uri as link
```

The key here is the new `download` attribute for the anchor tag. This will pop up a save as requester instead of navigating to the image.

You can also chose to hide the link and show it when it's initialized. You get the idea..

Comment: Thanks, `canvas.toDataURL()` is a native supported method?

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo yes, it's native and part of the canvas standard.

Answer (score 0):

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
document.body.appendChild(image); // or whereever you want.
```

**edit:** `onload` event handler is only required for server-loaded images.

Answer (score 0):

// create save tag then

var data = canvas.toDataURL(); // default is png add param image/jpg if you want to
document.getElementById('save').href = data;